# Why is Loop in Python Script Tool Validation only Looping Once?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool, parameters, tool-validation

My Python Script tool (ArcGIS Desktop 10.2) has two `getParameterAsText` inputs.

The first parameter is populated by the `initializeParameters(self)` module in the validation script which selects all CSVs in a particular folder.  Obviously set to 'Input' and 'Multivalue = yes'  **It works fine.**

The second parameter is populated by the `updateParameters(self)` module in the validation script by:

1) taking one CSV at a time (from parameter 1), and according to the information in its name...

2) pulling the proper path + file name from a "settings" (dbf) table with which to populate the second parameter, which is 'Output' and obviously set to "Multivalue = yes'.

**The Problem**:

If I select multiple CSVs from Parameter 1 the "Target_FCs" list only has the first corresponding path + file name appended to it (again, via the "settings" (dbf) table as described in step 2, above).

There are no problems with the values from my "settingsTable" (e.g. "mypath").

***Quite sure the issue is*** that the `for row in cursor` line is only working the first time, just don't know why and how to make it work each time through the `for csv in CSVs.split(';')` loop.

BTW - I can confirm that the `for csv in CSVs.split(';')` loop is working correctly.  If I choose 3 CSVs from Parameter 1, this loop is traveled 3 times, but the `for row in cursor` is only traveled once.

Validation Code Snippet:

```
import arcpy
import os

  def updateParameters(self):
    settingsTable = os.path.join(os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0],"Settings_CSV_to_ASMAD_FC.dbf")
    cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(settingsTable)
    Target_FCs = []

    CSVs = str(self.params[0].value)
    x = 0
    if self.params[0].altered:
      for csv in CSVs.split(';'):       
        if csv.upper().find("SMALLSITES") != -1:
          datatype = "SmallSites"
        elif csv.find("BIGSITES") != -1:
          datatype = "BigSites"
        if csv.upper().find("INACTIVE") != -1:
          activity = "Inactive"
        elif csv.upper().find("ACTIVE") != -1:
          activity = "Active"

        for row in cursor:
          myname = row.getValue("Name")
          mypath = row.getValue("Location")
          if myname == datatype + "_" + activity: 
            Target_FCs.append(mypath)

        self.params[1].value = Target FCs

    return
```

CSV contents are not relevant to this question, only their names. Some names could be: "BIGSITES_ACTIVE.csv", "SMALLSITES_INACTIVE.csv", etc...

Settings Table looks like this:

```
Name                    Location
BIGSITES_ACTIVE         Q:\Data\Sites.gdb\BigSites_Active
BIGSITES_INACTIVE       Q:\Data\Sites.gdb\BigSites_Inactive
SMALLSITES_ACTIVE       Q:\Data\Sites.gdb\SmallSites_Active
SMALLSITES_INACTIVE     Q:\Data\Sites.gdb\SmallSites_Inactive
```

It's really just a lookup table to determine where the new FC (that is to be created from the CSV) is to be stored.

Comment: This is may not solve your problem, but it is better to replace `cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(settingsTable)` with `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(settingsTable) as cursor:`

Comment: @ahmadhanb  Thanks.  I believe you are correct, that is a better way to script a cursor.  Problem is now I'm getting errors on my validation script.  All I did was copy your line of code over my original cursor line and indented the rest of my script (very careful in doing so).  But I realize this is a secondary problem and will have to be for another question.  For now, I'm still hoping for an answer to this one.  But thanks again all the same.

Comment: If you do switch to the arcpy.da version, it should be `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(settingsTable, ['Name', 'Location']) as cursor:` .  Ie, it requires a second parameter specifying which fields to include in each row (and the order of those fields) - use '*' to specify all fields (including geometry).  You can then access those values as `row[0]` and `row[1]`, repectively.

Comment: I would suggest adding some debugging code to write to a file.  This may confirm if it is in fact running through each row as expected, and for each CSV as expected.  Eg, at the beginning of the function, something like `file = open("/path/to/debug-file.txt","w")` and then under the `for row...` and just before the `if myname`, add something like `file.write("{}, {}, {}, ".format(csv, myname, mypath))`.  (Of course it's better to use `with` with `open` and if you don't you should also `close` near the end of the function).  Then see what you get in your debug file.

Comment: Apologies @SonofaBeach  - I can understand your confusion.  I've added the samples from my CSV and dbf ("Settings") table you requested to the end of my question.  As you can see "Location" points to a "mypath" value which is in fact a "path+file name".